# no resource found in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am getting this error while creating a new android application project in `eclipse Juno in mac`.

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: `Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme'). AndroidManifest.xml /testProject    line 10 Android AAPT Problem`

Also it is not creating a mainactivity as it used to do before. `Recently I've upgraded android SDK tools  to rev 24.0.1.`

Kindly help me.

Comment: same problem happened with me i have to use my backup of eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this issue follow these steps.

- Update **ADT** plugin of eclips
- Make sure that AppTheme is defined in the styles.xml file.
- Use latest **AppCompat** library if you consider backward compatability.
- Make sure that your **compiling** and **target versions are set to
  21.** Its because the new AppCompat only compiles on 21.

  Right click the project and click **"Properties".** Then select **"Android"** from the tree on the  left. You can then select the target target version on the right.

  **Note:** Make sure your properties, classpath and project files are writable otherwise it won't work